# Where does the euro/dollar rate data prior to 2002 come from?

Tags: exchange-rates, history, currency-exchange, eurodollar

The Euro was created in 1999 and introduced in 2002. But if you search for the euro/dollar rate data there is a rate value back to Aug 1983.

[image: Screenshot from Google]

Where does this data come from?

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a source for the google exchange rate, but my best guess is that it is based on ECU ([European Currency Unit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Currency_Unit)). ECU was predecessor of euro set up in 1979.

When Euro was set up it exchanged with ECU at parity so technically it’s possible to use ECU/USD exchange rate in place of EUR/USD exchange rate.

Comment: [Currencies are provided by Morningstar](https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/#:~:text=The%20Finance%20Data%20is%20obtained,impressions%2C%20and%20Google%20Finance%20impressions.).  It most likely uses ECU, yes. Systems like Bloomberg offer data prior to the beginning of the ECU, based on synthetic Bank of England calculations. You can also find Deutsche Mark, Italian Lira etc on most systems, because there are still outstanding bonds.